# Why is it that '0 is false, but 'False is true?

Tags: hy

I was playing around with symbols and was surprised to see that:

```
hy 0.18.0 using CPython(default) 3.7.3 on Linux
=> (bool '0)
False
=> (bool 'False)
True
=>
```

Is that a design decision? What is the best way to represent boolean values on Hy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'0` isn't a symbol; it's a `HyInteger`, which inherits from `int` and behaves like an `int` in many ways. In particular, it uses `int`'s `__bool__` method.

`'False` is indeed a symbol (`HySymbol`), but most operations on a symbol, including `bool`, don't try to evaluate the symbol. Instead, they treat it like a string. At least for the time being, `HySymbol` inherits from `str`. So, `bool` on any nonempty symbol returns `True`. For the same reason, `(+ 'x 'y)` returns the string `"xy"` even if you've set the variables `x` and `y` to numbers. If you want to Booleanize the value of a variable represented by a symbol, rather than the symbol itself, say `(bool (hy.eval 'False))`.

> What is the best way to represent boolean values on Hy?

With a plain old `bool`, as in Python.